# Making first name, last name a required attribute rather than an optional one in Django's auth User model

Tags: python, django, forms, validation, authentication

I'm trying to make sure that the first name and last name field are not optional for the auth User model but I'm not sure how to change it. I can't use a sub class as I have to use the authentication system.

Two solutions I can think of are:

1. to put the name in the user profile but it's a little silly to have a field that I can't use correctly.
2. To validate in the form rather than in the model. I don't think this really fits with Django's philosophy...

For some reason I can't seem to find a way to do this online so any help is appreciated. I would have thought that this would be a popular question.

Cheers,
Durand

Comment: You also have the option of modifying the model in your Django installation, but that's obviously not a great option either.

Comment: Yeah, true but I guess its not very portable. This current project isn't really supposed to be but it sets a bad precedence for others.

Comment: Totally. Unfortunately I don't think there's really going to be a totally clean solution for this. Django really needs a way to let you override the `User` model but still allow use of `contrib.auth` and friends.

Comment: I would go with validating in the form. This is a very non-intrusive solution and let's you reuse all the auth user framework with little coding, in what way do you think it's against django's philosophy?

Comment: Because then validation would only work from within forms and not other input methods. I think I'll take your suggestion and go with forms though. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely go with validating on the form. You could even go as far as having more form validation in the admin if you felt like it.

Comment: It does seem like the best option. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

#### Simplest solution

- Just create a custom **UserRegisterForm** which inherits the django's default `UserCreationForm`.
- The `first_name` and `last_name` are already attributes of django's default `User`. If you want to make them as required fields, then recreate those fields as `forms.CharField(...)`.

Now use your own User register form.

```
# Contents usersapp/forms.py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


# Inherit Django's default UserCreationForm
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50) # Required
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50) # Required
    # All fields you re-define here will become required fields in the form

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Mbuso for the advice. Here's my full implementation for those who are interested. Before taking a look at the source, let's see what it looks like:
[image: Admin Web Screenshot]

I've implemented a profile model, but this will work just fine without it.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from apps.profiles.models import Profile


# Define an inline admin descriptor for Profile model
# which acts a bit like a singleton
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'profile'


class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    def clean_first_name(self):
        if self.cleaned_data["first_name"].strip() == '':
            raise ValidationError("First name is required.")
        return self.cleaned_data["first_name"]

    def clean_last_name(self):
        if self.cleaned_data["last_name"].strip() == '':
            raise ValidationError("Last name is required.")
        return self.cleaned_data["last_name"]


# Define a new User admin
class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    form = MyUserChangeForm
    inlines = UserProfileInline,


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)
```

Note: If you do implement a profile model, recommend using `UserProfile` as the name, since is this is what's in the documentation and seems to be the standard (this part was developed before I started working on the project). If you're using Django 1.5 or higher, skip `UserProfile` all together and extend the `User` model.

Answer (score 1):

The Django way of extending the basic User model is through user profiles: see "[Storing additional information about users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users)".

If it does not fit your needs, django.contrib.auth is just a Django application, I would simply fork it. As long as you abide by the original interface, I think you will be out of trouble.

Another option is [Pinax](http://pinaxproject.com/) - it has OpenId support built in, you can use it with your own openid provider. [OpenId](http://openid.net/) native support is a [battery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/#other-batteries-included) I really miss in Django.

Comment: Pinax looks cool, I've have to use it in other projects but this one is meant to be very simple right now. Thanks!