# django registration: what's the up-to date 'canonical' way to extend 'contrib.auth.models.User'

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

premises:

1) Environment: django 1.3, python 2.6, dev: across several platforms, prod: RHEL

2) I would like to enable site staff to add users (from admin site). The way that they fill in on just ONE page 'username', 'email', 'password1', password2' AND 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'skype'. Click 'OK' and it's done.

3) I've searched through the docs and web and found only quite outdated sources, non-working ideas and some sources which might work but deal with modifying django itself (which I found difficult to deploy and maintain)

What are your tips to do this job in most clean (easy, transparent, simple whatever) way?

So far, this article and it's comments was the most useful source I've found:  http://scottbarnham.com/blog/2008/08/21/extending-the-django-user-model-with-inheritance/

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making first name, last name a required attribute rather than an optional one in django's auth User model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466851/making-first-name-last-name-a-required-attribute-rather-than-an-optional-one-in)

Comment: I don't think inheritance from User model is advised by any official django documentation, is it?

Comment: Yes, they don't speak too much about it. That's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the recommended way of doing it is through UserProfile:

```
#models.py
class MySiteProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    join_date = models.DateField()
    # and whatever additional fields you want

#admin.py
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

admin.site.unregister(User)

class MyUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [MySiteProfileInline, ]

admin.site.register(User, MyUserAdmin)


#inlines.py
class MySiteProfileInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = MySiteProfile
```

Comment: Yes, the recommended way is UserProfile, definitely. But it doesn't solve the problem without modifying other files inside django installation, which I doubt is recommended.

Comment: I don't understand. I thought you said you wanted everything pertaining to the user editable on one page? The code above does just that using inlines.